# li Class of 'active' not targetable by CSS

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I've done this 1000 times, and this may be because I'm frustrated that I can't figure it out, but I am having so much trouble changing the appearance of my nag bar links based on the active page.

I'm using Codeigniter, so here is my navbar code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <?php if ($this->uri->segment(1) === FALSE) { echo "<li class='active'>"; } else { echo "<li>"; } ?><a href="/">home</a></li>
                <?php if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'about') { echo "<li class='active'>"; } else { echo "<li>"; } ?><a href="/about">about</a></li>
                <?php if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'music') { echo "<li class='active'>"; } else { echo "<li>"; } ?><a href="/music">music</a></li>
                <?php if ($this->uri->segment(1) == 'contact') { echo "<li class='active'>"; } else { echo "<li>"; } ?><a href="/contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Second, here is the CSS that's *Supposed* to change the appearance of the links:

```css
#wrapper .nav ul li .active a {
    color: grey;
    cursor: default;
}
```

I'm at a complete loss of why this doesn't work. If someone would be so kind as to knock me upside the head and remind me why I'm an idiot that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is the space between li and .active

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removed the `li` before `.active` like so:

```
#wrapper .nav ul .active a {
    color: grey;
    cursor: default;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7SdD/)

You were trying to style a child of `li` with the class `.active`

Alternatively, you could also use:

```
#wrapper .nav ul li.active a {
    color: grey;
    cursor: default;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7SdD/1/)

...either work.

Comment: Fantastic! Its the small things. Thanks!